# Lines of Code in a MS-Access Database

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to find the number of lines of code used in an MS-Access database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-CountLines.html) article shows you how. [BTW it was an easy google...)

Answer (score 4):

Once again, I should refer to [MZ-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/edit/177631) az a very interesting tool for VBA/Access. It will give you number of lines (code versus comment) per proc/module. It also allows you to number automatically your lines. You will then be able to use the undocument Erl property in your error management procedure. This Erl property gives you the number of the line where error was raised.